# Difference operation from root

Tags: openscad

Is there a way to make difference directly from root? I want to do something like this:

```
difference(){
    root();
    cube();
}
```

instead of this:

```
difference(){
    union(){
        object1();
        object2();
        .
        .
        objectN();
    }
    cube();
}
```

Comment: Are you asking if there is a special collection named "root" containing all of the objects that have already been rendered?  The answer to that is is "no".  Once an object has been rendered, it's popped off the stack.  The built-ins such as parent_module() and $parent_modules only report what's on the stack, not objects that are already gone.

Answer (score 1):

You are already on the there. You just need to define `root()` and `cube()` as modules like so:

```
difference(){
  root();
  cube();
}

module root(){
  object1();
  object2();
  ...
}

module cube(){
  //some cube definition
}
```

In the background OpenSCAD will secretly create a union() around every module for you, just as if you wrote:

```
module xyz(){
  union(){
    //objects
  }
}
```

So in this example an object `root()` is created and `cube()` will be subtracted from this object. By using the module definition you keep your code just as modular as you ask for.

You may also want to have a look at the official docu and cheat sheet [here](http://www.openscad.org/cheatsheet/).

Answer (score 0):

difference() module subtracts all other children from the first one. In first snippet, first child is root(), in second first child is union(), and in both cube is subtracted.